# TableLayoutPanel and StatusTrip toolbar overlapping

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, tablelayoutpanel, statusstrip

I have a winforms vb.net app. In this winform I have placed two components:

- TableLayoutPanel
- StatusStrip toolbar

I am trying to put StatusStrip toolbar at the bottom of the winforms and TableLayoutPanel to fit all the rest of the screen, so I set below properties for this two components:

- TableLayoutPanel: Dock:Fill
- StatusStrip toolbar: Dock:Bottom

The problem is that TableLayoutPanel and StatusStrip toolbar overlaps, that is, StatusStrip toolbar appears over TableLayoutPanel at the bottom of the winforms.

I have tried to put TableLayoutPanel within a panel, and StatusStrip toolbar within another panel as well, and then set the dock properties for panel, the one containing tablelayoutpanel to fill and the one containing StatusStrip toolbar to bottom but it does not work.

Comment: It is just a simple Z-order problem.  Right-click the TLP and select Bring to Front.

Comment: Yes, that works! thanks!

Answer (score 16):

The problem is the hierarchy of your controls. This can be changed using the [Document Outline window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/46xf4h0w%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (Ctrl+Alt+T, or View>Other Windows>Document Outline). Drag the `TableLayoutPanel` to above the `StatusStrip`.

**Wrong (notice the overlap)**
[image]

**Right**
[image]